# error "Cannot seek vector iterator after end" when using std::fill_n

Tags: c++

The error tells me I go out of bounds. I don't see how. I simply reserve(n can be big) and then try to initialize my vector with 0s.

I am compiling with the Microsoft visual studio compiler in Debug mode

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int n;
vector<int> rows;
int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    rows.reserve(n);
    fill_n(rows.begin(), n, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `reserve` call only sets the containers capacity, not the size. The vector is still empty. You want `resize`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah I see, I guess resize increases the capacity too?

Comment: Yes it sets both capacity and size. What's better is that it also default initialize all the elements, which for `int` will mean zero initialization. So you don't need the `fill_n` call after.